# what is this error “Access violation at address at 00000000. read at address 00000000”"

Tags: windows, runtime-error

I recently downloaded an application. but when i try to start running it it throws me an error stating this "Access violation at address at 00000000. read at address 00000000"" I couldnt understand the error

application was "ExtraVis" link:http://www.win.tue.nl/~dholten/extravis/

i tried running it in windows 7 64 bit as well as windows XP 32 bit

could anyone have faced the same error and resolved it ?

Comment: `Please note: ExTraVis requires a PC running Windows XP, preferably with a graphics card that supports anti-aliasing (AA). If no AA is available, set its value to "0" in "data/open_gl_settings.ini"` Have you done this?

Comment: @Will.Beninger yes i have done it. i have mention in my statement i have installed in windows XP 32 bit. But still its not working

Comment: It was the bit about the `AA` that I was really making reference to. Have you verified that your card supports `AA` or have you changed its value?

Comment: @Will.Beninger Yes my card supports AA and also i have checked the settings as well.!! still i am facing this error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237028/how-to-track-down-access-violation-at-address-00000000 Well here is a reference to the question on StackOverflow. They recommend some apps to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

With all the zeros, it looks like what programmers call a NULL dereference. This is a programming error. You really can't "fix" it, it's a problem in the code. Unless you're a programmer and have the code for the program, there's not much you can do.

There's a very small chance this is due to corruption someplace. Maybe there's a bad block on a disk, or a bad entry in the Registry is causing this, and a reinstall will help. But it's unlikely.

I'd check for updates for your program. See if they've fixed the bug. If not, reinstall, in the < 1% chance this will help, but you have no real other tools to try.

Comment: There is no installation for this software its a direct zip file and its a stand alone application ..!!! Thank you for explaining . I need this tool to work because my intership depends on it ...!!!

Answer (score 0):

[MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/) is a great tool to track down this kind of troubles precisely.

Possibly, you need to run your software inside something like "DOS emulator".